# Understanding connect-src, script-src and style-src when everything is loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, web, http-headers, fetch, content-security-policy

I am a little confused with the directives available with [Content Security Policy Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy). Mainly confused with `connect-src` , `script-src` and `style-src`

I have a javascript, which sends `Fetch`, `Ajax` (on the same domain) and dynamically loads a link tag that has a stylesheet.

If I have to get my script whitelisted on a domain, should this be part of all `connect-src`, `script-src` and `style-src` ? I am a little confused here.

To make it clearer, there is a script at `https://example.com` which loads, sends data from `https://example.com` and loads stylesheet sitting at `https://some-another-domain.com`. How should the content security policy reflect this? Should `connect-src` , `script-src` and `style-src` include both the domains?

Could someone help clarify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each directive should contain only sources which it covers (controls).

1. The `connect-src` directive [covers](https://csplite.com/csp81/) the URLs from which resources can be loaded using following script API interfaces(see the [test](https://csplite.com/csp/test25/)):

- `<a ping='...'>`
- `fetch()`
- `XMLHttpRequest()`
- `sendBeacon()`
- `WebSocket()` (hence `ws:`/`wss:` scheme can be specified in `connect-src`/`default-src` only)
- `EventSource()`

Therefore if you perform `XMLHttpRequest('https://example.com/ajax')` or use jQuery `$ajax('https://example.com/ajax')` which internally calls *XMLHttpRequest()*, you need to allow the `https://example.com` in the `connect-src`:
  `connect-src https://example.com;`
Similarly if you use `fetch('https://google.com/api/json')`, you need to add this host-source to the `connect-src`:
  `connect-src https://example.com https://google.com/api/;`
and so on for all 6 the APIs above.

> 

2. The `script-src` directive [controls](https://csplite.com/csp82/) 5 things:

- external scripts loading via `<script src='http://example.com/script.js'></script>`. You need to allow relevant host-sources in the `script-src` for that. Alternatively `'nonce-value'`/`'hash-value'` token can be used.
- inline script blocks like `<script>...</script>`. You need to use `'unsafe-inline'` or 'nonce-value'/'hash-value' tokens in the `script-src` to allow such scripts.
- `eval()`, `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()`, `Function()`, `setImmediate()`, `execScript()` funct calls are gated on the `'unsafe-eval'` source expression. If you use those you need to have `'unsafe-eval'` in the `script-src` (with some exceptions for `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()`).
- navigation to javascript-URLs like `<a href='javascript:...'>`.
- inline event handlers in tags like `<div onblur='...'>`, `<input onclick='...'>`.
   `*` for last 2 things you need to have 'unsafe-inline' in the `script-src` directive or use `unsafe-hashes` + `'hash-value'` tokens paired (supported with some bugs as for now).

> 

3. The `style-src` directive [covers](https://csplite.com/csp88/) several things(see the [test](https://csplite.com/csp/test64/#test)):

- stylesheet requests via `<link href='http://example.com/min/css.css' rel='stylesheet'>`. In this case you need to add `http://example.com` host-source to the `style-src` directive.
- stylesheet requests from the CSS `@import url('https://example.com/style_import.css')`
- stylesheet requests from a Link HTTP response header field `Link: https://example.com/file.css; rel=stylesheet`.
- inline style blocks: `<style>...</style>`. You need to have `'unsafe-inline'` or `'nonce-value'`/`'hash-value'` in the `style-src` to allow these.
- *style=* attribute in tags: `<tag style='color:green; margin:0 auto;'>`. You need to have `'unsafe-inline'` in the `style-src` to allow these. Or use paired the `'unsafe-hashes'` + `'hash-value'` (is not widely supported as for now).
    `*` JS call `setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')` is considered as `<tag style='display:none;'>` above.
- using of `CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()`, `CSSGroupingRule.insertRule()`, `CSSStyleDeclaration.cssText` and `CSSStyleRule.selectorText` was intended to be gated to `'unsafe-eval'` in the `style-src`, but it's not implemented yet.

Any usage of the above constructs (even via script calls) requires to allow relevant sources or tokens in the `styler-src` directive.

Comment: What about the case where the stylesheet is included dynamically using javascript? Does that form a part of connect-src, script-src or style-src?

Comment: Yeah, any dynamic creation/modifying of elements `<link href='...' rel='stylesheet'>`, `<style>...</style>` or `<tag style='...'>` is a subject of regulation `style-src` directive. It does not matter is it done using a `document.createElement('style')` or via `Element.innerHTML = ` or via `document.write()`. But assigning `Element.style.property = '...'` does not cause a Content Security Policy violation (`el.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'`; `el.style.display = 'none'`, etc).

Comment: Really interesting resource.